# LAG function unable to capture the previous record information when used in join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, lag

I have two tables:

`Employee`:

| Employee | Phone Num | StartDate | EndDate | Dept | DeptName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 5478765 | 12-Jan-23 | 29-Jan-2023 | 5 | Physics |
| 50 | 8756544 | 29-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-9999 | 6 | Chemistry |

`EmployeeSalary`:

| Employee | Salary | StartDate | EndDate | Dept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 5000000 | 12-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-9999 | 6 |

I want to join these two tables, from `EmployeeSalary` table I need the salary information whereas from `Employee` table, I need the last phone number i.e. the phone number which was entered in the period 12-Jan-23 and 29-Jan-2023 Phone number --> 5478765 and the current department name.

I am joining these two tables and using `LAG` function to extract the previous phone number. But when this is joined using `EmployeeID` and `DepartmentNumber` it is not showing the previous phone number.

I need output like this:

| Employee | Salary | StartDate | EndDate | Dept | PhoneNumber | DepartmentName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 5000000 | 12-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-9999 | 5 | 5478765 | Chemistry |

Comment: So what is your question...? "I need" isn't a question. What is the difficulty *you* are having solving the problem? What are you attempts? Why aren't they working?

Comment: Why does `Dept` have a value of `5` in your expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT es.Employee,
       Salary,
       es.StartDate,
       es.EndDate,
       prevDept,
       prevPhone,
       DeptName
FROM EmployeeSalary AS es
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Employee,
               Dept,
               DeptName,
               LAG(PhoneNum) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY StartDate) prevPhone,
               LAG(Dept) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY StartDate) prevDept
        FROM employee
    ) AS e
        ON e.Employee = es.Employee
           AND e.Dept = es.Dept;
```

| Employee | Salary | StartDate | EndDate | prevDept | prevPhone | DeptName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 5000000 | 2023-01-12 | 9999-12-31 | 5 | 5478765 | Chemistry |

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/7CwuiD-s)

Answer (score 2):

Just another option if an Employee has more than two roles.

**Example**

```
Select E.Employee
      ,S.Salary
      ,StartDate = E.D1
      ,EndDate   = E.D2
      ,E.Dept
      ,E.DeptName
      ,E.[Phone Num]
 From  (
        Select *
              ,D1 = min(StartDate) over (partition by Employee)
              ,D2 = max(EndDate) over (partition by Employee)
              ,RN = row_number() over(partition by Employee order by EndDate desc)
         from Employee
        ) E
 Join EmployeeSalary S on  E.Employee= S.Employee 
                       and E.EndDate = S.EndDate
                       and E.RN = 1
```

**Results**

```
Employee    Salary   StartDate   EndDate     Dept   DeptName    Phone Num
50          5000000  2023-01-12  9999-12-31  6      Chemistry   8756544
```

Comment: Thanks John for responding. Cetin's answer was closer to what I was lookin for.